# Trying to show full row results instead of just one cell

Tags: mysql

I have been using this query in MySQL workbench to look for the max invoice date where the order type is filler and i get a single result showing just the date. but i wanted to know how to display the complete row for the reuslts so i can see the invoice number, client name etc.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT max(invoice_date)
from invoice_data
where order_type = "filler";
```

**Results**

```
31/01/2023
```

any help would be amazing thank you.

Comment: Pls share what is your expectation, expected result, current behaviour, sample data, `invoice_data` schema ... so we could understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join to get all the columns (this could return more than one row) :

```
select i.*
from invoice_data i
inner join (
  SELECT order_type, max(invoice_date) as max_invoice_date
  from invoice_data
  where order_type = "filler"
) s on s.order_type = i.order_type and s.max_invoice_date = i.invoice_date
```